# What does this Matlab line mean?

Tags: c++, matlab

```
Histogram(j, :) = Histogram(j, :)./sum(Histogram(j, :));
```

To port into C++, I understand Histogram would be a multidimensional array. What does "./" mean in this line?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./ is the command for element-wise division (.* being the multiplication version).  The default for MATLAB is matrix operations, so you have to use the ./ command to tell it to do the operation element-wise rather than the matrix operation (which, in most cases, will fail because most of the time people intend the element-wise one).

Element-wise division means dividing the first element of one matrix by the first element of the second, then the second element by the second element, third by the third...until all are done, returning a matrix the same size as both the first and second.  This is instead of the matrix operation, where you invert the second matrix and do the matrix multiplication of the two to return a third matrix that may or may not be the same size as any of the parent matricies.

In the example above, assuming Histogram is a 2-D matrix, the element-wise and matrix operations are actually the same since

```
sum(Histogram(j,:))
```

will return a single, scalar value (the sum of the elements in row j).  The author of the code you are quoting probably just did the ./ command by default since that's a common MATLAB programming habit.

Comment: right, `sum` reduces the dimension by one, making it different from the other argument, and since MATLAB doesn't have implicit singleton expansion except for scalars (octave does), it must be producing a scalar.

Comment: To add to this comment, that statement is also ensuring that the histogram for the j^th row is normalized and is converted into a PDF so that you aren't calculating how often a particular value occurs, but what the probability of encountering that particular value is.